# Django get the max PK

Tags: sql, django, orm

I am trying to recieve the max PK using django ORM.
By max I mean I want to do this query:

```
SELECT MAX(pk_column)
FROM   some_table;
```

the thing is that I want something like `some_table_model.max(pk)` , it is important for me that the Django will translate it to the query above so it will use indexs. So:

1. Is there something like that build in?
2. Is there a way to write a generic function without doing it for a specific model?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-over-a-queryset) to get the Max value. For example, if you wanted the max ID of your Users table:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import Max

users = User.objects.all()
max = users.aggregate(Max('id'))
```

This would give you `{'id__max': 10}` or whatever the greatest ID is.

Comment: Do you happen to know what query it translates to?

Comment: You can get the SQL of any query by doing sone_queryset.query, but I'm not sure how to do the same once you use aggregation...

Comment: yes I know that I can get the query. I just wondered if you know what the query of the `aggregate` will be. it is a little strange that something with `aggregate` will produce a query like the one I am hope for.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit old, but I came across this same problem and it can be achieved using `latest`. something like

```
try:
    return some_table_model.ojects.latest('pk').pk
except some_table_model.DoesNotExist:
    return 0
```

this is of course assuming that your pk's are numeric and not composite. Otherwise you could use `id` or some other field as suggested above

Answer (score 2):

easy. you only need to get pk of the latest object:

```
YourModel.ojects.latest('pk').pk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
YourModel.objects.all().order_by(-id).first().id
```

Comment: this method will translate into a query that uses `order by` and `rownum = 1 (limit 1)` ... and that is exectly what I'm trying to avoide

Answer (score 0):

Here are four different ways to get the max PK, along with the accompanying SQL queries on an OpenMRS database on MySQL 8 (it's what I had available). Only the aggregation uses `MAX()`:

```
from django.db import connection
from django.db.models import Max

c0 = Concept.objects.all().order_by('-concept_id').values_list('concept_id')[0]
# this is just the last object in the queryset
# this will *mostly* give you the highest PK, but rather not rely on it
c1 = Concept.objects.last().concept_id
# get the latest object by concept_id
c2 = Concept.objects.latest('concept_id').concept_id
# use aggregation, this is the only one of these methods that uses MAX()
c3 = Concept.objects.all().aggregate(Max('concept_id'))

# show the last 4 SQL queries
connection.queries[-4:]
```

`connection.queries` is a list of dicts with sql and times, so we massage it a bit with

```
print("\n".join([q['sql'].replace("`", "") for q in connection.queries[-4:]]))
```

to get the following four corresponding SQL queries:

```
SELECT concept.concept_id FROM concept ORDER BY concept.concept_id DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT concept.concept_id, concept.retired, concept.short_name, concept.description, concept.form_text, concept.datatype_id, concept.class_id, concept.is_set, concept.creator, concept.date_created, concept.version, concept.changed_by, concept.date_changed, concept.retired_by, concept.date_retired, concept.retire_reason, concept.uuid FROM concept ORDER BY concept.concept_id DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT concept.concept_id, concept.retired, concept.short_name, concept.description, concept.form_text, concept.datatype_id, concept.class_id, concept.is_set, concept.creator, concept.date_created, concept.version, concept.changed_by, concept.date_changed, concept.retired_by, concept.date_retired, concept.retire_reason, concept.uuid FROM concept ORDER BY concept.concept_id DESC LIMIT 1
SELECT MAX(concept.concept_id) AS concept_id__max FROM concept
```